# Why would syndaemon disable only tap-to-click?

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 on a Gigabyte Aero 14. The Aero includes an Elantech touchpad. Output of xinput is:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ E-Signal Keyboard                         id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Bluetooth Mouse M557                      id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ E-Signal Keyboard                         id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB 2.0 Camera                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Gnome starts up syndaemon on startup as follows:

```
david@Aero:~$ ps -A | grep syn
 2691 ?        00:00:00 systemd-timesyn
 4152 ?        00:00:00 syndaemon
david@Aero:~$ ps -fp 4152
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
david     4152  4025  0 20:40 ?        00:00:00 syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R
```

syndaemon does a great job of preventing tap-to-click events during keyboard activity - **but** clicking the hardware mouse button while typing is still active.

To reproduce:

1. Open a terminal, start typing
2. Tap-to-click anywhere outside the terminal; taps are ignored
3. Click the hardware mouse button outside the terminal; taps register

I don't see any manpage options for syndaemon to intercept / ignore these hardware clicks. Is there another way?